# Mongoexport auth error using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1"

Tags: mongodb

I have taken over undocumented Mongo 4.4.8 cluster (PSA). I am trying to tidy it up and test thouroughly.

An original connection string:

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://${USER}:${PASS}@10.0.0.3:27017,10.0.0.6:27017,10.0.0.2:27017/bud?replicaSet=bud-replica&authSource=admin
```

I have enabled localhost and socket connection. I can log in from cmdline with

```
mongo -u ${USER} -p ${PASS}
MongoDB shell version v4.4.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("492e331b-417e-458a-83c7-9db6eaae0869") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.8
```

I can switch db to *bud* and perform the queries. But if I run just

```
mongo
```

then the authentication with the same credentials does not work:

```
bud-replica:PRIMARY> db.auth('admin','admin');
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

I tried to search for users but shows there arent any:

```
bud-replica:PRIMARY> db.getUsers()
[ ]
bud-replica:PRIMARY> use bud
switched to db bud
bud-replica:PRIMARY> db.getUsers()
[ ]
```

This is `mongod.conf` security part:

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
   keyFile: "/etc/bud-rs"
```

Finally I need to export my data before doing experiments. Though the cmd line interface looks similar, mongoexport cannot fetch the data, regardless I set user/password or skip these arguments.

```
mongoexport -h localhost --db=bud -u ${USER} -p ${PASS} -c=accidents --jsonArray > accidents.json
2021-08-25T19:30:30.631+0200    could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
mongoexport -h localhost --db=bud -u ${USER} -p ${PASS} -c=accidents --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase “admin” > accidents.json
2021-08-25T19:36:18.738+0200    could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
root@10:~# mongoexport -h localhost --db=bud -u ${USER} -p ${PASS} -c=accidents --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase “bud” > accidents.json
2021-08-25T19:38:21.174+0200    could not connect to server: connection() error occured during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

I am really confused and I failed to find a solution on Google or SO.

Second relevant question:

If I need to create new user, shall I do it on all replicas or it is automatically synchronized?

**1st update**

This is the workaround, but my questions are still valid. I want to understand.

```
root@10:~# mongoexport --db=bud -u ${USER} -p ${PASS} -c=accidents --jsonArray "mongodb://admin:admin@10.0.0.3:27017/bud?authSource=admin" > accidents.json
2021-08-25T20:46:54.777+0200    connected to: mongodb://[**REDACTED**]@10.0.0.3:27017/bud?authSource=admin
2021-08-25T20:46:55.778+0200    [........................]  bud.accidents  0/4379  (0.0%)
2021-08-25T20:46:56.497+0200    [########################]  bud.accidents  4379/4379  (100.0%)
2021-08-25T20:46:56.497+0200    exported 4379 records
```

**2nd update**

```
bud-replica:PRIMARY> use admin
bud-replica:PRIMARY> show collections
system.keys
system.users
system.version
bud-replica:PRIMARY> db.system.users.find()
{ "_id" : "admin.admin", "userId" : UUID("769e4f5c-6f46-4153-857e-47d7d8730066"), "user" : "admin", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "32/AP4019eome36j8n
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The user credential was created in the admin database.

When connecting with the mongo shell, switch with `use admin` before running `db.auth`

The mongoexport command that worked used `authSource=admin` in the connection string.

Add `--authenticationDatabase=admin` to the other command line to direct it to use the admin database for auth as well.

Comment: Great, that makes sense finally. Is the content of this collection synchronized across the replica? The query on the secondary failed because of connection issues to an arbiter.

Comment: Replicated to secondary, yes; to arbiter, no.  In my opinion arbiters are more trouble than they are worth, just use another secondary.

Comment: I wanted to reuse the existing VPS with nginx as the arbiter. It shall not use many resources.

Comment: I had the same error happening while using a MAC. Even with "--authenticationDatabase=admin" or "--authenticationDatabase admin", it still gave me the error. Come to find out, it you have a special character in your password like a "$", then you may have to escape it with \$\. Once I did this, I was able to run my MongoDB commands like "mongoexport".

Comment: adding --authenticationDatabase=admin to the end of my command worked! ty

Answer (score 14):

whole example command as below worked for me.

Mongodb version: 5.x.x, also for Mongodb version: 8.x.x

```json
mongodump --authenticationDatabase=admin --uri mongodb://username:password@mongodb-host/db-name?ssl=false&authSource=admin
```

Answer (score 4):

When connecting use --authenticationDatabase=admin

Comment: Your answer duplicates the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongodump "mongodb://username:password@host:27017/?authSource=admin" --db dbname --out path\file.sql
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.