# MongoDB Docker On AWS EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, host

My one of the production grade MongoDb Database running on AWS Ec2. So Now the things is When I try to taking backup from Mongodb database onto Host meaning that I'm not going into container, I'm taking directly backup from host. Below is commmand i Used but when I run the command it's showing me below error.

Can you please help me on this

Command : docker exec  sh -c 'exec mongodump -d  -u  --password 'PASSWORD'  --out=backup'

`Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.`

1.) I have tried onto host direct writing above command but showing the below error

```
`-bash: !2: event not found`
```

2.) Tried Via script but facing same error as above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoexport auth error using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927857/mongoexport-auth-error-using-mechanism-scram-sha-1)

Comment: When I used or apply article which you sent. I'm facing below error!!

-bash: !2: event not found