# Mongo DB - Login issue with role - Unable to login with non-root role

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have a DocDB (MongoDB Instance) running on AWS. I'm using PyMongo and MongoShell for accessing the DB.
And, I was able to login with master credentials perfectly fine. I tried to create a new user annd update the permissions.

`docdb_admin.command('updateUser', 'svc_ise', roles=[{'db': 'admin', 'role': 'readWrite'}])`

I cannot login using the "svc_ise" account.

But, when I tried this - This worked perfectly fine.
`docdb_admin.command('updateUser', 'svc_ise', roles=[{'db': 'admin', 'role': 'root'}])`

I could login if role is root on both, Pymongo and MongoShell.

But, cannot login if role is "read" or "readWrite" or "dbAdmin" or "UserAdmin" nothing worked.

I need to create a non-writeable or read access only account for this database. Can someone point me any clues for this?

MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
I'm trying authenticate to admin db only everytime.

**Mongoshell response:**

```
ravi@PC14737S:~$ mongo --ssl --host abc-docdb-provision-XXXXXX.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username svc_ise --password
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://abc-docdb-provision-XXXXXX.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/
MongoDB server version: 4.0.0
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2023-04-05T18:29:31.807-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed
```

Tried multiple roles but failed to login other giving it a root role.
Seeking community's help regarding this login issue.

Update:
Recreated another DocDB instance , now it shows i could login. But I run the `show users;` command.

**CLI Logs:**

```
ravi@PC14737S:~$ mongo --ssl --host abc.efgh.ks.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --username svc_ise_read --password
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://abc.efgh.ks.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/
MongoDB server version: 5.0.0
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
rs0:PRIMARY> use admin;
switched to db admin
rs0:PRIMARY> show users;
2023-04-06T14:13:43.260-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authorization failure :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getUsers@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1686:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:799:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:706:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

**Failure Logs from Cloudwatch Audit:**

```
{
    "atype": "authenticate",
    "ts": 1680740196642,
    "remote_ip": "10.XX.XX.XX:3784",
    "user": "",
    "param": {
        "user": "svc_ise",
        "mechanism": "",
        "success": false,
        "message": "Authentication failure",
        "error": 18
    }
}
```

Comment: Credentials should be in the admin database, try `--authenticationDatabase=admin` https://stackoverflow.com/a/68937584/2282634

Comment: I tried that  --authenticationDatabase admin , but still same error - login failed.

Comment: Get the server log so you can see why it failed.

Comment: Retrace your steps, you're doing something wrong or just entering the wrong password. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/role_based_access_control.html

Comment: The readWrite role doesn't grant the viewUser privilege, try running `db.runCommand("connectionStatus")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MongoDB and DocumentDB's READ role doesn't have ViewUser privilege action on the builtin role. We need to add that action.

I could resolve this issue using an RBAC policy. I created a custom role policy like

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "CustomViewUsers",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "admin", collection: "" }, actions: [ "viewRole",  "viewUser"] }
     ],
     roles: [
       { role: "read", db: "admin" }
       ]
   }
)
```

And attached that role to the user account.

```
db.grantRolesToUser("svc_ise_read",["CustomViewUsers"])
```

Then I could run the "UsersInfo" command or the "show users" without any issue.