# Getting error while trying to ping MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I am getting error when trying to ping the mongoDB with the following connection string:

```
mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/?tls=false&replicaSet=rs0&readpreference=secondaryPreferred
```

The error:

```
error occurred during connection handshake: EOF
```

TLS is not configured. No able to understand the issue.

If I removed the tls from the connection string.
I get the following error:

```
connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism \"SCRAM-SHA-1\": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Not sure what is the issue. I am using Golang as framework.

Comment: For the second issue, try adding `authSource=admin` to the connection string: `mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&readpreference=secondaryPreferred&authSource=admin`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927857/mongoexport-auth-error-using-mechanism-scram-sha-1