# cant connect to mongoDB using docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

I am building an application in GoLang and MongoDB was working fine but suddenly it stopped connecting and gave this error:

```bash
panic: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Following is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongo:
    image: "mongo:latest"
    container_name: "mongo"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - "web.network"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
      - mongodb_config:/data/configdb
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  redis:
    container_name: "redis"
    image: redis:alpine
    ports: 
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - "web.network"
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: "0auth"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/app"
    restart: "always"
    environment:
      - Replica= {{.Task.Name}}
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - redis
    networks:
      - "web.network"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
networks:
  web.network:
volumes:
  mongodata:
  mongodb_config:
  redis-data:
    driver: local
```

this is the line where it throws the error:

```golang
client, err := mongo.Connect(
        context.TODO(),
        options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("MONGO_URI_DOCKER")))
```

My `MONGO_URI_DOCKER` is:

```
mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&authSource=custom-auth&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
```

Can someone help me figure-out this problem?

> NOTE:- The application works perfectly fine without docker on local system.

Comment: Your client is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, not to the URI you show as the environment variable.

Comment: Could you exec to your web app and use `curl -v mongo` or `nslookup mongo` to see if the name gets resolved to an ip address

Comment: I also think that your `MONGO_URI_DOCKER` is not set right in the app , how are you using the env?

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927857/mongoexport-auth-error-using-mechanism-scram-sha-1) can help

Answer (score -2):

It's seems like the issue with networks. Please modify the networks and you don’t need to create any kind of networks.

```
networks:
   connection_containers:
   driver: bridge
```

And run with `docker compose up --build`

I hope you will get solution. And make sure you pass the mongodb image name instead of localhost.

Thanks

Comment: What change are you proposing exactly to `networks:`, and why would it result in the application seeing a 127.0.0.1 address?